# Is my VIS 180 the 50 Lumen or 70 Lumen Version?

Tags: lighting, taillight

So, I bought a Light and Motion Vis 180 off of Ebay.  The seller had a great rating and claimed it was in "new" condition, so I thought I'd go ahead and take a risk on it.

What I got was a Vis 180 - of some kind.  Sure, it seems to work, but I have packaging from three different products!

I have packaging from a Vis 180 50 Lumen, a Vis 180 70 Lumen, and a vis 180 micro.  In fact, here is a picture to prove it:

[image]

(The white package is 50 Lumens.)

Now I still have a perfectly good Cygolite Hotshot.  I went in a darkened room, and it appeared the hotshot was actually brighter than the vis180 *but* the vis180 had a vastly larger "throw" - by itself, the vis180 made a bright spot on the wall, and together with the vis180 it made a bright spot on the much larger spread of light from the vis180.  (Confession: Haven't charged it yet.)  Makes me think it's the 50 Lumen, I can post a picture of that too...

Perhaps they would make a great combination with the vis180 flashing to get attention and the Hotshot on steady so drivers can judge where I am?

I ride some really hostile roads at night - broken glass, no sidewalks, where there are sidewalks, I'm shooting across roads where drives are sometimes frustrated they can barely hang a right.

As such, I did want the 70 lumen version.  I paid $70 for it but I could still return it.  I don't truly care about the packaging - hell, I live next to a corporate outlet store and know **sometimes** underpriced product can be legit, but could someone be so kind as to tell me how to figure out what I actually own?

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is definitely the Vis 180 70 lumen. This is the new packaging that L&M just debuted in late 2014 when the 70 lumen model came out. They sent the new design to the packaging manufacturer just before they got the Vis 180 upgraded to run at 70 lumens, so the white insert says 50 lumens when in fact it's 70 lumens (as shown on the outside sticker there). Another way to double-check is the flash pattern. Does the pulse turn all the way off at its least-bright point or does it only go to about 20% dim? If it goes all the way off, it's the 50 lumen version, if it stays part-way on throughout the cycle, it's the 70 lumen version. You can see a video comparing the old and new flashes on [the full Vis 180 review](//www.bikelightdatabase.com/light-and-motion/vis180/) on the bike light testing site I run.

To clarify on the packaging, all of their lights that are in a series come in the same packaging within that series. So if you buy an Urban 350, the inset has info about the whole Urban line, including the 350, 500, 650, and 800. When you bought the Vis 180, you got info about the Vis 180 and the Vis 180 micro, because they're sold in the same package with a different label on the outside.

The Cygolite Hotshot puts out much less total light, but has a more focused, intense beam than the Vis 180. The total output of the Vis 180 is much higher. I personally use the Vis 180 as my primary taillight in steady mode, with a secondary (less bright) light in flashing mode. Your proposed setup could work well too. Having two lights is always a good idea!

So, you almost certainly do have a legitimate Vis 180 2014 70 lumen version. One thing to be aware of is that the eBay seller is likely *not* an authorized reseller, so [your warranty may be void](https://support.lightandmotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/200204979-Warranty-Policy):

> Light & Motion provides warranties against manufacturer defects for 2 year starting from the date of purchase **from a Light & Motion Authorized Dealer**. While the warranty is non-transferable and does not cover failures from misuse or battery issues beyond one year, damaged lights can usually be repaired for a nominal fee. Proof of purchase required for warranty support.

They have more information [specifically about buying from eBay here](https://support.lightandmotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/201828310-Online-Sales-Amazon-Ebay-Purchases-Warranty). I would suggest you inquire as to whether the seller is an authorized dealer – in my experience, L&M have excellent customer support, but you may be SOL if you bought from an unauthorized source.